# How can I get history, with commit comments, for all changes for specific data range, specific directory path and specific branch

Tags: git

I'm working with large codebase (40GB repo) and I cant afford to switch branches and checkout other branch because their external dependency system will clear current setup (and it is a nightmare to redownload trillion of GB of data every time) yet somehow, I need to find out the following:

- find all changes in `Source/Some/Custom/Dir`
- ideally, for just `*.cs` files
- starting from July 3 2022 up to September 1 2022
- in (remote) branch `origin/extra_branch` (different from my current)
- display it as commit history with comments and files changed **or/and** changes itself

Comment: `git log --name-status --since=2022-07-03 --until=2022-09-01 origin/extra_branch -- 'Source/Some/Custom/Dir/**.cs'` perhaps?

Comment: That seems to be it... it there a way to make path work as inclusive rather than exclusive. so basically "show all entries that include changes in this path, not just SOLELY entries in this path"?

Comment: Throw `--full-diff` into the mix.

Comment: Add as an answer

Comment: Note that, while not required here, `git worktree add` is handy for dependency-system issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
git log --name-status --since=2022-07-03 --until=2022-09-01 origin/extra_branch -- 'Source/Some/Custom/Dir/**.cs'
```

Some notes:

- `--since` and `--until` inspect the committer date, not the author date. This means, for example, if the branch was rebased recently (after 2022-09-01), then none of the rebased commits would be listed because the committer date is later than 2022-09-01.
- Replace `--name-status` with other options that control the output, e.g., `--stat`, `--patch`, `--name-only`.
- The double-asterisk in `.../**.cs` ensures that paths are inspected in lower directories recursively.
- As usual, the provided pathspec ensures that only commits are found that make changes to these paths. Additionally, only these paths are listed. To get the complete change in the commit, add `--full-diff`.